# Visualforce page embeded in page layout is not coming with 100% width in lighting compact density

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforcedx, css, slds

I have a visualforce page embeded in pagelayout and page is showing the 100% width for comfy but for compact it is not showing 100% width. Can any one tell me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the detail page in Lightning? can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @sanketkumar i have attached the screenshot. This is taken when density is set to compact. Width has been set to 100%  for visual force page and it is showing 100% in comfy density but for the compact density it is not covering the 100% width.

Comment: It looks like it is still accounting for the label when switching to compact mode. I have the same issue and when I choose to show the option to show label for the visualforce on the object detail layout it then fills the 100% width. The problem is that although label is not being shown, the compact mode thinks there is still something there.